# Able to Authenticate user in Firebase authentication but could not able to store data in Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, rx-java2

I am able to authenticate user by Firebase authentication but could not able to store data in Firebase database. I am not getting any error in logcat. I haven't changed any rules in Firebase database. My rules are set default. Here is my code:

```
fun authenticateUser(){
    Observable.create(ObservableOnSubscribe<Task<AuthResult>>{
        e: ObservableEmitter<Task<AuthResult>> -> run {
        try {
            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email!!, password!!)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, object : OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> {
                        override fun onComplete(p0: Task<AuthResult>) {
                            e.onNext(p0)
                            e.onComplete()
                        }
                    })
        }
        catch (ex : Exception){
            dialogs?.dismiss()
            displayMessage("network problem..")
            e.onError(ex)
        }
    }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(object : Observer<Task<AuthResult>>{
                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

                override fun onNext(t: Task<AuthResult>) {
                    if (t.isSuccessful) {
                        storeData()
                    }
                    else if (!t.isSuccessful){
                        dialogs?.dismiss()
                        displayMessage("some issues has came..")
                    }
                }
                override fun onComplete() {
                }

                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                    compositeDisposable?.add(d)
                }
            })
}

override fun storeData() {
    var currentUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser
    val databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.reference.child("Users_Information").child(currentUser?.uid)
    val data = HashMap<String,String>()
    data.put("name",nameString!!)
    data.put("email_address",emailString!!)
    data.put("image","def")
    data.put("thumb_image","def")

    databaseReference.setValue(data).addOnCompleteListener {
        task -> if (task.isSuccessful){
                dialogs?.dismiss()
                displayMessage("user is created")
                goToNextActivity()
        }
        else if (!task.isSuccessful){
        dialogs?.dismiss()
        displayMessage("Authentication failed, try again later")
     }
        else if (task.isComplete){
        displayMessage("data not stored")
     }
    }
}

override fun goToNextActivity() {
    var intents = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
    intents.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
     intents.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
    startActivity(intents)
    finish()
}
```

Uid is generating but data is not storing in Firebase database.I debug the code but didn't find any issue. Where is the problem, please help...

Comment: Firebase already running asynchronous, why do you using Observable?

Comment: @KemalTürk i tried without observable also but getting same issue..

Comment: You can try ValueEventListener instead of addOnCompleteListener.Or you can try POJO class instead of HashMap.Or you can try database rules true.

Comment: @KemalTürk There is no such listener with setValue() method and i think ValueEventListener is used to read data from database. I also tried after changing the rules but didnt find any solution. My issue is still persist.

Comment: Do you have child currentUser.uid in "Users_Information" but data is not storing ?

Comment: @eurosecom yes i have , "firebaseDatabase.reference.child("Users_Information").child(currentUser?.uid)"

Comment: I use setValue(user) where user = new User("xxx", "xxx","xxx")  i do not use val data = HashMap... like in setValueAsync(users);

Comment: @eurosecom No, still not working.. i just tried as u said,, I am still able to authenticate but my data is still not storing ..

Comment: Did you get displayMessage("data not stored") ?

Comment: Try to call setValue(user) without listener and check your child‌​(currentUser?.uid) on Firebase console.

Comment: @eurosecom No , i didnt get displayMessage("data not stored") , my dialog bar is keep showing. nothing happened. i just get my authenticate key toast..I feel now my dataReference is wrong thats why its not working..

Comment: It looks like your ObservableEmitter does not emitt onNext.

Comment: @eurosecom I tried without listener now but my issue is still persist..

Comment: @eurosecom " 
It looks like your ObservableEmitter does not emitt onNext"  Noo,, this cant be happened,, if it is then i wouldn't get toast of my authenticate key ..

Comment: Do you call createUserWithEmailAndPassword with the same  email!!, password!! ?

Comment: @eurosecom yes..

Comment: If userid exist try to call mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)...

Comment: @eurosecom yes i am able to signIn with email and password but issue is still same..

Answer (score 0):

Try to send Firebaseuser to storeData() and try to log Firebaseuser in storeData()

```
override fun onNext(t: Task<AuthResult>) {
                if (t.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d("FB user", t.getResult().getUser())
                    storeData(t.getResult().getUser())
                }
                else if (!t.isSuccessful){
                    dialogs?.dismiss()
                    displayMessage("some issues has came..")
                }
            }

....
..

  override fun storeData(curentUser: Firebaseuser) {
      Log.d("FB user", currentUser?.uid)
      val databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.reference.child("Users_Information").child(currentUser?.uid)
...
..

 }
```

Comment: Do you see right uid in Log.d("FB user", currentUser?.uid) in storeData() ?

Comment: May be if child(currentUser?.uid) exists in child("Users_Information") Firebase does not save data. Try to remove.

Comment: yes I saw the right uid.. Now I'll try to remove firebase and add it back.. I hope it will work ..

Comment: No nothing working ,, did everything to make it work but didn't find any solution. I tried to remove Firebase and configured it again but this also didnt work for me..Now i upgrade my Firebase to 11.8.0 but still having same issue...